# MySQL SELECT * FROM table1,table2,table3

Tags: mysql

I have several tables with same structure. All I want is get all results from all tables from a database.

For example:

Table1:

```
id |  Name  
-----------
1  |  John
2  |  Alex
3  |  Patrick
4  |  Donald
5  |  Jane
```

Table2:

```
id |  Name  
-----------
1  |  Ben
2  |  Dale
3  |  Kane
4  |  Tom
5  |  George
```

My desired result with **SELECT Name FROM ...** is:

```
 Name  
-------
John
Alex
Patrick
Donald
Jane
Ben
Dale
Kane
Tom
George
```

Is there any way to do this easily without using UNION like: **SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2 UNION SELECT * FROM table3....**

Because this makes my query so long and it is pain for me.Probably I'll have more than 20-30 tables in a database. I'm looking for somethings like **SELECT * FROM table1,table2.. etc.**

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

---

---

I did it like this (in PHP), I hope it also helps for others:

```
$dbc1 = $db->query("SELECT group_concat(table_name) AS tables FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='dbname'");
```

This query return all table names as 1 string with comma seperated like this : **table1,table2,table3....**
 Then I explode that string and I used in foreach loop.

```
$dbc1_ftchd = $dbc1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
foreach(explode(',',$dbc1_ftchd['tables']) as $next_tb_name){  
        echo $next_tb_name.'<br>';
    }
```

Now I able to use all tables as I want one by one instead of use all of them at the same time. But no problem it is return same result for me.

Thanks to everyone who helped me :)

Comment: In what sense do you mean "long"? It takes too long, or the length of the query string is "too long"? If the latter, do you mean too long for the RDBMS to accept, or too much typing?

Comment: Having 20-30 identical tables is a sign something has gone horribly wrong with the database design.

Comment: I mean query string is too long, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table1, table2, ...` is a JOIN, it performs a cross-product, not a union. `UNION` is really the only reasonable way to do this.

Comment: Erm, maybe improve the design of your database

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT `Name` FROM `Table1` 
UNION
SELECT `Name` FROM `Table2` 
UNION
SELECT `Name` FROM `Table3`
```

**EDIT:** Sorry, I didn't saw the last paragraph of your question. You can create a view or temporary table if you don't like UNIONs that much.

Create View: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html

Create Temporary Table: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmp_table AS (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [MERGE Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/merge-storage-engine.html) to create a virtual table whose contents are the union of a set of other tables:

```
CREATE TABLE AllTables (
    ... -- column definitions
) ENGINE=MERGE UNION=(Table1, Table2, ...)
```

Then you can use `SELECT Name FROM AllTables`.

Answer (score -1):

No, UNION is the clause used for such things.

Answer (score -1):

Without a `UNION` you can do it with a `FULL OUTER JOIN`... but this is inadvisable.

```
SELECT
    ISNULL( Table1.Name, Table2.Name ) AS Name
FROM
    Table1
    FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Name <> Table2.Name
```

(I'm not totally confident this will work in MySQL, I don't know if it supports `<>` in `JOIN` expressions)

Comment: It supports pretty much any conditions you might want (and then some); but it does not support FULL OUTER JOIN.